# Parsing JSON in java

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse JSON in android but am having trouble with accessing sub children of an object. I am trying to extract augment from the following,

```
{"augment-list": {
  "time": "12:01",
  "channel": "channel1",
    "augment": [
      {"id": "123", "name": "here", "x": "5", "y": "10", "orientation": "up", "content": "some stuff"},
      {"id": "456", "name": "there", "x": "12", "y": "25", "orientation": "down", "content": "more stuff"},
      {"id": "789", "name": "over there", "x": "1", "y": "2", "orientation": "left", "content": "and more"}
    ]
}}
```

I've tried accessing the augments by getting the JSON object of augment-list named augment, or augment[0] but cant figure it out how to access each augment inside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without more detail of what's going wrong, I can't tell what the problem might be.  Are you getting errors?  Can you post some code?

Do you have something like this?

```
json.getJSONObject("augment-list").getJSONArray("augment").getJSONObject(0).getInt("id")
```