# How to convert a javascript Map into a Java Map

Tags: javascript, java, dictionary

I'm using Rest Services, I recive an object like this:

```
{"1":{"3":"tres"},"2":{"1":"uno","2":"dos"}}
```

and I want to convert it into something with this type: `Map<String, Map<String,String>> map;`

Comment: How do you get the data from JS to Java? Transmitting JSON would work. Easy to produce in JS, lots of parsers for Java.

Comment: [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541125/parsing-json-in-java)